# How to create a regex that replaces two or more consecutive identical characters with only two?

Tags: java, regex

Assuming you have a twitter message that is similar to the following:

```
"Hoot, this is soooooo coooool!!!"
```

I want to come up with a Java regex so that String.replaceAll will result in the following:

```
"Hoot, this is so cool!"
```

I started and have tried permuting the following without success:

```
original.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1");
```

Does someone know how to come up with a regex that will greedily reduce several consecutive characters to two characters? The solution must not reduce two repeating characters to one (e.g. the word hoot should not reduce to hot).

Comment: Do you want `"so"` or `"soo"`?

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description.  If solved as stated, 'soooooo' would go to 'soo'.

Comment: @Thomas that's the problem stated in the title.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no...the OP shows "sooooooo" being replaced with "so", vs. "cooooool" being replaced with "cool".  The former is replacing with 1 char, the latter is replacing with 2.  IOW: just what Thomas stated: The "rules" asked for don't match the example solution he gave.

Comment: @CrayonViolent again, that's the problem OP's facing (regarding the results he/she posted). See dasblinkenlight for a good solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think you are still missing the point.  That is *not* the problem as stated by the OP. The OP said his problem is that he wants 2 or more chars to be replaced with 2 of those characters.  dasblinkenlight presents a good solution for that, yes, but if you look at the OP's example, he is NOT showing a replacement of 2+ chars for 2 chars for both examples "so" and "cool".  He is showing a replacement of 2+ for ONE character for the word "so", and 2 for "cool".  IOW, the example shows what he *really* wants is for repeated characters to be stripped to *show correct spelling*

Comment: dasblinkenlight even specifically points out how his solution will NOT address the inconsistency in the OP's example!

Comment: @CrayonViolent a typo maybe?

Comment: I don't think so...because he goes on to explain how he doesn't want it to behave the same for "hoot" vs. "hot".  See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to replace 2+ characters with exactly two, you can slightly modify your expression, like this:

```
original.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1$1");
```

However, there is not enough information in a regex to make an exception for `"soooooo"` and trim it to `"so"`, as opposed to `"soo"`.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/Yrd2Ma).

Answer (score 1):

With pure regex, the best you will get is what dasblinkenlight showed, but your issue extends beyond simply replacing 2+ chars with those 2 chars.  What you *really* want is for it to strip extra repetition for correct spelling of words, given the context of the word.

Examples:

- "this is sooooo cool" to be reduced to "so", not "soo" - strip 1+ to 1
- "this is so cooooool" to be reduced to "cool" - strip 2+ to 2
- "this is hooooot" to be reduced to "hot" - strip 1+ to 1 because the 
  intention is the word "hot" not "hoot"
- "What a hooooooot" to be  reduced to "hoot" - strip 2+ to 2 because
  in this context, the intention is "hoot" not "hot"

There is no pure regex solution for this. Regex cannot do spell and grammar checking.